# COM UIA event called only after unregistering

Tags: c#, com, c++-cli, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm using the MS UIA (COM) through a C++/CLI interface, and my C# application is using that C++/CLI interface (let's call this interface/dll as uiacpp)

I created the event handling mechanism in uiacpp mostly following the examples in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff625914(v=vs.85).aspx

The problem I'm facing is, the event handler I register to UIA is only called after I unregister the same event (same everytime / different events / event types & tests). When I register the event, I can see that the QueryInterface method of my event class gets called twice, obviously from UIA, so UIA does something with it. Then I fire the event in my test, but nothing happens. And the moment I unregister the event the QueryInterface is called a couple of more times, then event handler is called, then the release method gets called for the remaining references (about 6 more of them at this point) made by UIA to cleanup things.

Here is the code:

The C++/CLI class:

```
class CppUIAutomationEventHandler :
    public ::IUIAutomationEventHandler
{
private:
    LONG _refCount;

public:
    int _eventCount;
    gcroot<UIAMan::IUIAutomationEventHandler^> myHandler;
    static std::list<IUIAutomationEventHandler*> *EventRegister;

    // Constructor.
    CppUIAutomationEventHandler() : _refCount(1), _eventCount(0)
    {
    }

    // Constructor.
    CppUIAutomationEventHandler(
        UIAMan::IUIAutomationEventHandler^ aHandler)
        : _refCount(1)
        , _eventCount(0)
        , myHandler(aHandler)
    {
    }

    // IUnknown methods.
    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef()
    {
        ULONG ret = InterlockedIncrement(&_refCount);
        return ret;
    }

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release()
    {
        ULONG ret = InterlockedDecrement(&_refCount);
        if (ret == 0)
        {
            delete this;
            return 0;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppInterface)
    {
        if (riid == __uuidof(IUnknown) || riid == __uuidof(IUIAutomationEventHandler))
            *ppInterface = static_cast<IUIAutomationEventHandler*>(this);
        else
        {
            *ppInterface = NULL;
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
        }
        this->AddRef();
        return S_OK;
    }

    // IUIAutomationEventHandler methods
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE HandleAutomationEvent(::IUIAutomationElement * pSender, EVENTID eventID)
    {
        _eventCount++;

        myHandler->HandleAutomationEvent(gcnew CUIAutomationElement(pSender, false), eventID);

        return S_OK;
    }
};
```

and here is a ref (managed c++) class method that C# calls to register the event (by using the last code at the end):

```
void CUIAutomation::AddAutomationEventHandler(
    int eventId
    , IUIAutomationElement^ element
    , TreeScope scope
    , IUIAutomationCacheRequest^ cacheRequest
    , IUIAutomationEventHandler^ handler)
{
    ::IUIAutomationElement* el = safe_cast<CUIAutomationElement^>(element)->getElement();
    ::IUIAutomationEventHandler* _handler = new CppUIAutomationEventHandler(handler);
    LastHResult = puia->AddAutomationEventHandler(
        eventId
        , el
        , (::TreeScope)(int)scope
        , (cacheRequest != nullptr) ? ((CUIAutomationCacheRequest^)cacheRequest)->getElement() : NULL
        , _handler);
    CppUIAutomationEventHandler::EventRegister->push_back(_handler);
};
```

I'm using a list of handlers to use while unregistering them. Also puia is a COM pointer that was created by:

```
CUIAutomation::CUIAutomation()
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    ::IUIAutomation* _puia;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL,
                    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUIAutomation,
                    (void**)&_puia);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        puia = _puia;
}
```

And finally, this is the C# calls:

automationhandler class implementation using the uiacpp:

```
    class AutomationHandler : IUIAutomationEventHandler
    {
        public AutomationHandler()
        {
        }

        public void HandleAutomationEvent(IUIAutomationElement sender, int eventId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IUIAutomationEventHandler called");
        }
    }
```

and the C# register / unregister lines:

```
var aHandler = new AutomationHandler();
uia.AddAutomationEventHandler(UIA_EventIds.UIA_Window_WindowOpenedEventId, uia.GetRootElement(), TreeScope.TreeScope_Subtree, null, aHandler);

// for debugging
bool loop = true;
while(loop)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}

uia.RemoveAutomationEventHandler(UIA_EventIds.UIA_Window_WindowOpenedEventId, uia.GetRootElement(), aHandler);
```

Comment: Because that means either using pinvoke or tlbimp to have an interface created for C# first. And you cannot monitor details of the COM calls with that approach. I'm using my own custom-created interface in C++ instead. And might I add, but cannot prove yet, that using those automatic interfaces for C# seems to be working less stable. That's why.

Comment: What do you think that System.Windows.Automation "managed" code is using to communicate with the UIAutomationClient COM interface? But yes, you're right, my initial answer was a bit wrong. Anyways, your question helps with nothing along answering the OP.

Comment: And I do not have any control (or monitoring) on what's happening there. And I don't want to deal with more of Microsoft's bugs that I cannot fix. Aren't these already enough reasons? Anyways, please stay on topic, this is far off topic.

Comment: So you don't know why this code (which is almost a replica of the example in msdn) wouldn't work for events?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133934/discussion-between-mattapiroglu-and-dan).

Comment: Why are you using COM to access you C++/CLI interface. You can do it directly from C#. You don't need COM at all....

Comment: @xMRi you misunderstood. This code is not c# - com - c++/cli.  It's c# - c++/cli - com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These COM events are dispatched via the windows message loop.

That combined with the fact that you don't pump messages between register and unregister, results in the events being delayed until you unregister and return to the main message loop.

One solution would be to use `await Task.Delay` instead of a blocking sleep.

Comment: @MattAPiroglu: Callbacks can't happen on a sleeping thread in native code either (APCs can, if you use `SleepEx` with `bAlertable = TRUE` instead of `Sleep`, but COM doesn't use APCs).  It's really well known that all code using COM must pump messages.  Perhaps your native C++ version initialized COM with a multi-threaded apartment, and the callback actually came in on a different thread?